# weird django file upload error

Tags: python, django, file-upload

although, there are many topics for this, i cannot find the right question+answer among them
my problem is this:

i am trying to write an file upload. once i submit the form, this error is coming:

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /anzeige_save/
Key 'file' not found in <MultiValueDict: {}>
```

this is my model:

```
class Anzeige(models.Model):
    titel = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    anzeige = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    datum = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='/anzeige/D-d-M-Y/')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.titel
```

this is my view:

```
if request.path == '/anzeige_save/':
    anzeige=Anzeige(titel=request.POST['titel'], anzeige=end_anzeige,date=datetime.datetime.now(), datum=request.POST['datum'],file=request.FILES['file'])
    anzeige.save()
    return HttpResponse("Anzeige saved successfully")
```

this is my ajax in front-end:

```
var title = document.getElementById(title).value;
var body = document.getElementById(body).value;
var file = document.getElementById(name_file).value;
var datum = document.getElementById(datum).value;
if(title==" " || body==" " || title=="" || body=="" || datum=="" || datum==" " ){
alert("Please fill out all!");
}else{
    $.ajax({
    url: "/anzeige_save/",
    type: "POST",
    data: {anzeige:body,titel:title,file:file,datum:datum},
}).success(function(data){
    $(succ_message).text(data);
    $(succ_message).fadeIn(1000);
    $(succ_message).fadeOut(2000);
})
 }
```

and this is file in form:

```
...
<input type="file" id="name_file" name="name_file" size="40" maxlength="100000"><br />
...
```

am i missing something here ?

i have Model with filefield and i am saving other fields including file into instance.

thanks for any drop-by! :)

Comment: Can you post your template form?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/zCc9t0Xs   this is my form template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your form is multipart:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

Forgetting this is a common cause of your error.

**EDIT:** File uploads are not possible through ajax*. There are a few options:

1. Post the form
2. Post the form in an iframe if you don't want the page to refresh
3. *Not strictly true. You can use the [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) object (not supported in older browsers)

Comment: oh okay, i will try to post the form in a normal way then

Comment: will this be then like ajax, or page-refresh is there?

Comment: It will be like posting the form (page refresh is there)

Comment: are you sure about page-refresh?, i saw that small example in jquery site, the page is not refreshing,

Comment: See option 2) Posting within an iframe ;)